# Any apps that can show a chronological record of your phone’s movement?

Tags: iphone, applications, sleep-wake, data

I used to have a sleep tracking app Rise Sleep, that would show almost like a seismograph of the degree of motion detected by the phone around the clock. In this way if you fell asleep on your bed for a nap then you could see when you fell asleep for instance and when you picked your phone back up after waking. But that a) costs money and b) anyway no longer seems to work on my device.

Is there anything that simply shows the chronic seismograph?